# SMPS power supply - fuse resistor calculation

Tags: power-supply, resistors, switch-mode-power-supply, design, fuses

I'm designing a [TNY288](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/328/tinyswitch-4_family_datasheet-1511375.pdf)-based SMPS. My transformer input inductance is 931μH. I'm using a 320V MOV and have a doubt about the fusible resistor calculation.

The output load is 12W, the input capacitor is 22μF 450V. (Circuit flow -> input - fusible resistor - MOV - common mode choke 22mH - bridge - 22μF, 450V capacitor - transformer.)

Can anyone help me out regarding what ohm and watt values my wirewound flameproof resistor should be?

Please also give design equations.

Comment: What's the worst case scenario you need to withstand without fusing? Usually minimum input voltage with maximum load and worst case efficiency.

Comment: That'll be 90C AC RMS @ 230mA calculated for efficiency.

Comment: Good. How much voltage drop and power loss can you accept for your series resistor?

Comment: Ummm, how do you decide that? For now, I don't have any limitations as such, but I guess a few Watts (maybe 3W?) should be my limit.

Comment: Usually by thermal and PCB size limitations. Are you ready to drop 25 % efficiency over just your series resistor?

Comment: Naa. So that should be 2W/3W

Comment: That’s still a lot but whatever, it’s your design. P = I^2 x R. 3 = 0.23^2 x R. Solve for R.